# Is there a way to use encrypted passwords on Prisma ORM database config?

Tags: encryption, orm, passwords, prisma

I'm starting with Prisma ORM and I want to know if it's possible to encrypt the database's password on prisma file on the  snippet where we put the database config.

My .env file:

```
DATABASE_PASSWORD="postgresql"
DATABASE_USER="postgres"
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://${DATABASE_USER}:${DATABASE_PASSWORD}@localhost:5432/example_db?schema=public"
```

My prisma file:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Book {
  id          String @id @default(uuid())
  title       String
  description String
  bar_code    String @unique

  @@map("books")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are always read from the system's environment and are not publicly accessible. You would normally not push the content of your .env file to GitHub. Also, note that the .env file is not a javascript file hence you would not be able to use third-party encryption libraries in that file. In conclusion, there is no way to encrypt passwords on Prisma ORM database config.